# Mvc 3 How to list all available routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, routes

How does:

```
@Html.ActionLink("MyText","Index","Home")
```

Translates to:

```
<a href="/Home">MyText</a>
```

Whereas before it was printing

```
<a href="/Home/Index">MyText</a>
```

After the I added a default action for all controller via:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "DefaultActionToIndex",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

It seems to me that the helper method does more than print whatever was passed in but is able to resolve the route dictionary and figure out that "Index" is not necessary since it was set as default.

The question is how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Routing works both ways, for incoming requests and URL generation, it tests the routes in  `System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes` (in order) with the provided the values (in this case `{ controller = "Home", action = "Index" }`), and uses the first route that matches. If a parameter has a default value, and the provided value is equal to that default value, it's not included in the URL.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how it reflects through the routes? I'm doing RouteTable.Routes, but I'm not seeing any property/method that would allow me to "tests the routes"

Comment: @Alwyn See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.getvirtualpath